# Given a list of dictionaries, how can I eliminate duplicates of one key, and sort by another

Tags: python, algorithm, list, sorting

I'm working with a `list` of `dict` objects that looks like this (the order of the objects differs):

```
[
    {'name': 'Foo', 'score': 1},
    {'name': 'Bar', 'score': 2},
    {'name': 'Foo', 'score': 3},
    {'name': 'Bar', 'score': 3},
    {'name': 'Foo', 'score': 2},
    {'name': 'Baz', 'score': 2},
    {'name': 'Baz', 'score': 1},
    {'name': 'Bar', 'score': 1}
]
```

What I want to do is remove duplicate names, keeping only the one of each name that has the highest `'score'`. The results from the above list would be:

```
[
    {'name': 'Baz', 'score': 2},
    {'name': 'Foo', 'score': 3},
    {'name': 'Bar', 'score': 3}
]
```

I'm not sure which pattern to use here (aside from a seemingly idiotic loop that keeps checking if the current `dict`'s `'name'` is in the list already and then checking if its `'score'` is higher than the existing one's `'score'`.

Comment: Go with the loop, it's simple and clear.

Comment: Its Simple and Clear and easy to read in six months when you need to change it "slightly"

Comment: +1 There is something magic about this question in that it elicted a diverse and interesting set of answers.  It is fascinating how many completely different solutions this problem has.  I'm starring this as a favorite because of the rich answer set (am also upvoting every answer that has a creative or interesting solution).

Comment: @Raymond - thanks. I was excited to see the variety, too. I had a couple versions of it, but gleaned a much cleaner one from the list. Btw, I own and have read your book (Advanced Python, in case you have others), and it was great. I personally think you should write another book, maybe on extra advanced Python or on design patterns in Python.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One way to do that is:

```
data = collections.defaultdict(list)
for i in my_list:
    data[i['name']].append(i['score'])
output = [{'name': i, 'score': max(j)} for i,j in data.items()]
```

so output will be:

```
[{'score': 2, 'name': 'Baz'},
 {'score': 3, 'name': 'Foo'},
 {'score': 3, 'name': 'Bar'}]
```

Answer (score 10):

There's no need for defaultdicts or sets here.  You can just use dirt simple dicts and lists.

Summarize the best running score in a dictionary and convert the result back into a list:

```
>>> s = [
    {'name': 'Foo', 'score': 1},
    {'name': 'Bar', 'score': 2},
    {'name': 'Foo', 'score': 3},
    {'name': 'Bar', 'score': 3},
    {'name': 'Foo', 'score': 2},
    {'name': 'Baz', 'score': 2},
    {'name': 'Baz', 'score': 1},
    {'name': 'Bar', 'score': 1}
]
>>> d = {}
>>> for entry in s:
        name, score = entry['name'], entry['score']
        d[name] = max(d.get(name, 0), score)

>>> [{'name': name, 'score': score} for name, score in d.items()]
[{'score': 2, 'name': 'Baz'}, {'score': 3, 'name': 'Foo'}, {'score': 3, 'name': 'Bar'}]
```

Comment: This solution would be the most elegant if we were using a data structure like `{'Foo': 3}` instead of `[{'name': 'Foo', 'score': 3}]`. I would argue that the poster of the original question should be doing so.

Comment: This is my favorite solution. The only thing I would change is d.get(name,0) to d.get(name,score). This would allow negative scores also.

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun, here is a purely functional approach:

```
>>> map(dict, dict(sorted(map(sorted, map(dict.items, s)))).items())
[{'score': 3, 'name': 'Bar'}, {'score': 2, 'name': 'Baz'}, {'score': 3, 'name': 'Foo'}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorting is half the battle.

```
import itertools
import operator

scores = [
    {'name': 'Foo', 'score': 1},
    {'name': 'Bar', 'score': 2},
    {'name': 'Foo', 'score': 3},
    {'name': 'Bar', 'score': 3},
    {'name': 'Foo', 'score': 2},
    {'name': 'Baz', 'score': 2},
    {'name': 'Baz', 'score': 1},
    {'name': 'Bar', 'score': 1}
]

result = []
sl = sorted(scores, key=operator.itemgetter('name', 'score'),
  reverse=True)
name = object()
for el in sl:
  if el['name'] == name:
    continue
  name = el['name']
  result.append(el)
print result
```

Comment: +1 This answer is the only which doesn't morph the dataset. Looks consistent and dictionaries can have extra items if OP wants.

Comment: What's the purpose of using `object()` here?

Comment: @nomulous: It creates a new object that cannot possibly be found in the dictionary. `None` (or any other existing object for that matter) *could* (although it isn't in this case) be found in the data.

Comment: @Ignacio That's awesome! I just typed in `object() == object()` and the answer is `False`, which is really handy. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest way I can think of:

```
names = set(d['name'] for d in my_dicts)
new_dicts = []
for name in names:
    d = dict(name=name)
    d['score'] = max(d['score'] for d in my_dicts if d['name']==name)
    new_dicts.append(d)

#new_dicts
[{'score': 2, 'name': 'Baz'},
 {'score': 3, 'name': 'Foo'},
 {'score': 3, 'name': 'Bar'}]
```

Personally, I prefer not to import modules when the problem is too small.

Answer (score 2):

In case you haven't heard of group by, this is nice use of it:

```
from itertools import groupby

data=[
    {'name': 'Foo', 'score': 1},
    {'name': 'Bar', 'score': 2},
    {'name': 'Foo', 'score': 3},
    {'name': 'Bar', 'score': 3},
    {'name': 'Foo', 'score': 2},
    {'name': 'Baz', 'score': 2},
    {'name': 'Baz', 'score': 1},
    {'name': 'Bar', 'score': 1}
]

keyfunc=lambda d:d['name']
data.sort(key=keyfunc)

ans=[]
for k, g in groupby(data, keyfunc):
    ans.append({k:max((d['score'] for d in g))})
print ans

>>>
[{'Bar': 3}, {'Baz': 2}, {'Foo': 3}]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I can come up with an one-liner here:

```
result = dict((x['name'],x) for x in sorted(data,key=lambda x: x['score'])).values()
```