# Removing duplicates from list, keeping newest

Tags: python, algorithm, unique

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of dictionaries, eliminating duplicates of one key, sorting by another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123831/list-of-dictionaries-eliminating-duplicates-of-one-key-sorting-by-another)

Does anyone have any clever idea how to remove duplicates from my list of dictionary objects, where two keys should compare to equals and a third is a timestamp? The object that is to be left in the list should be the one with the latest timestamp.

To remove any ambiguity from my question I present a simple test case for my goal:

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
future = datetime(now.year + 100, *now.timetuple()[1:-2])

# Elements are considered equal if A and B matches.
data = [{"A":10,"B":20,"D":now}, \
        {"A":45,"B":20,"D":now}, \
        {"A":45,"B":20,"D":future}, \
        {"A":66,"B":6,"D":future}, \
        {"A":66,"B":6,"D":now}]

def make_unique(lst):
    pass

make_unique(data)

# data should now contain: (10,20,now),(45,20,future),(66,6,future)
print(data)
```

Performance is not terrible important, but the list could very well contain a couple of thousends of elements.

Comment: @FallenAngel: Nice find, that's indeed the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to create a dictionary `unique` and iterate on `data`. Make the tuple `(d['A'], d['B'])` your key and the corresponding item `d` your value. Then, it's a matter of checking whether (1) the key is already in the dictionary and (2) if the corresponding time stamp is more recent than the one stored:

```
unique = {}
for d in data:
    key = (d['A'],d['B'])
    if key in unique:
        if unique[key]['D'] < d['D']:
            unique[key] = d
    else:
        unique[key] = d
```

Then, just retrieve an unsorted list as `unique.values()`.

Comment: Thanks, I went with this approach.